# No examples are shown in Welcome screen of qtcreator

Tags: application-development, 18.10, documentation, qt-creator

So I installed *qtcreator* package on ubuntu 18.10.

I found out that to get the examples, I also needed the *qtbase5-examples* and the *qtbase5-doc-html* package.

But there are still no examples shown in the drop-down menu of the Welcome screen in qtcreator.

I found people with similar problem (for example for archlinux), but trying to fix the path problem does not allow the examples to show up in qtcreator.

Aynone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you have installed Qt Creator but not the Qt5 development libraries. Try installing the development libraries with:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Then try launching Qt Creator and see if the examples have appeared.

Comment: yes. you are almost right. That fixed the problem. But the package that is really needed is in fact **qtbase5-dev**

Comment: actually, `apt-get reinstall qtbase5-dev` made it.

Comment: @MatejKovac the qt5-default package includes the qtbase5-dev package.

Answer (score 3):

This may be an issue caused by not recognized qmake, i.e. QtVersion in Menu->Settings->Kits->Kits->QtVersion, showing `None`.

Manually choosing it to /usr/bin/qmake and will get correct qt version.

Then examples and Kits are both OK.